# Is it possible to write the 2 html codes in the same html file?

Tags: html

Is it possible to write the 2 html codes in the same html file and call it when required with help of name property

```
<html name ="abc1">
<body>
</body>
</html>

<html name ="abc2">
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance 
- Miss subanki

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you give an example?

Comment: you probably can do it another way.

Comment: can any1 here confirm Mr.Alec 's Answer ...i dont know PHP programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scripting language if you want to add conditions like these.

[PHP](http://php.net) example for `page.php?show=abc1`

```
<?php
if ($_GET['show'] == 'abc1') {
  echo 'something';
} elseif ($_GET['show'] == 'abc2') {
  echo 'something else';
}
?>
```

Comment: is PHP related DOS programming?

Comment: php is server side (I think you can run php scripts from command line if you installed it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is valid. Depending on what you're doing, couldn't you just do the same things with div tags?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="abc1">
      <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>

    <div id="abc2">
      <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alec's post that you should probably use a Server Side Scripting (http://www.w3schools.com/web/web_scripting.asp) to achieve what you are trying to do. It sounds like you are taking users input and deciding what to show them.

So a very high general overview of how server side scripting works is you generate a page request with information from the user and then on the server side, a script parses the url and decides based on the parameters passed in, what to show the user.

The desired effect of showing one section at a time can also be achieved through Javascript or any client side scripting - http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp